# Performing a query inside NHibernate entities

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, nhibernate

I have a repository of PinballMachines, which returns a hydrated `PinballMachine` entity.  It has a private property that is a list of games played on that machine.

A pinball machine can possibly have millions of games recorded against it.  From a `PinballMachine`, I want to get high scorers for display, this is the top 10 game players.

```
public class PinballMachine
{
    private IList<Game> _games = new List<Game>();  

    public virtual int ID { get; protected set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Game> GetTop10Games()
    {
        return _games
            .AsQueryable()
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Score)
            .Take(10)
            .ToList();
    }
}

public class Game
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Score { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
}
```

The `PinballMachine`'s `_games` property is mapped as a `Bag`.

```
Bag<Game>("_games", m =>
{
    m.Key(k => k.Column("PinballMachineID"));
    m.Access(Accessor.Field);
    m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
}, r => r.OneToMany());
```

The following code works behaves properly, however, NHibernate performs a very naive predicate on the games table, and performing the sort and filter in-memory.

```
-- SLOW! 1,000,000 records

SELECT ...
FROM Games
WHERE PinballMachineID = 123
```

This is very suboptimal as the database is transmitting millions of records when all I need is 10.

Ideally, I want NHibernate to generate a query that looks like the following:

```
-- FAST! 10 records

SELECT TOP 10 ...
FROM Games
WHERE PinballMachineID = 123
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Is it possible to configure my mapping so I can perform additional queries (on the database) on hydrated objects.

I am aware that I can use the NHibernate session to perform a linq query, but **I want this logic to part of my entity** instead.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774095/nhibernate-iqueryable-collection-as-property-of-root

Comment: That question looks like the same problem as mine, hopefully NHibernate has progressed enough to support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, NHibernate doesn't support that.

When you created the mapping for `PinballMachine`, you defined that one-to-many relationship on the ID column which fetches (lazily or eagerly) all the matching `Game` entities.

One thing that I would suggest is that the `GetTop10Games` looks like it should belong in a repository class, instead being a member of the entity. That's one of the reasons behind using a repository pattern - it encapsulates all the data access logic, and in turn even allows you to write specific performant queries when you really need them, every once in a while. That's (unfortunately or not) the problem with most ORM frameworks; you never know  when a certain LINQ provider will perform poorly, or even fail to translate into SQL at all, so you want to keep your options open.

I would certainly make this method a member of `IGameRepository` or `IPinballMachineRepository`, and implement it something like:

```
public IList<Games> GetTopGamesForMachine(PinballMachine machine, int maxItems)
{
     return Session
         .Query<Games>()
         .Where(g => g.PinballMachine == machine)
         .OrderByDescending(g => g.Score)
         .Take(maxItems)
         .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I think you're right, I am trying to do the DDD approach by having my entities have some behavior in them, I think it's currently a bad approach I've taken that my domain entities are the same entities that NHibernate returns.

Comment: Yes, even with ORMs, you cannot completely ignore the existence of the data layer and its mechanisms. You still need to open and close sessions (just like you would do in ADO.NET), make sure that they are open long enough (accessing a lazy property after a session has been closed will fail), be aware of transient entities and concurrency issues, etc. So, while you can abstract the actual way things are persisted, or have a completely different db schema than your domain model, and even abstract the very ORM you're using, from my experience you should never let this leak into your entities.

Comment: Would your recommendation to have Domain entities and NHibernate entities completely separate?  While this is beyond the scope of the original question, I have yet to a definitive example of an architecture that solves my problem.

Comment: @Matthew: it's hard to tell, but I wouldn't let the domain driven approach force you into smelly decisions, just for the sake of it. Does the `PinballMachine` really need to keep a collection of all its games, if there are many of them? Probably not, you don't get any real benefits from that. See [this article](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/01/15/Domain-Driven-Design-Aggregate-Root-Modelling-Fallacy.aspx): sometimes entities are meant to be organizational units, not containers.

Comment: Or [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451438.aspx) by Julie Lerman, namely the "Data Access Happens in the Repository, Not the Aggregate Root" part, where she shows one such repository method. I personally haven't succeeded to completely forget about persistence when doing my design, and usually try to organize my repository as needed by my domain problems, but still keep the data access outside the domain model. But, you might try asking a different question and possibly get better answers from someone who had different methodologies and experiences.

Comment: Thanks for the resources and advice, I've been trying to wrap my head around DDD for a while, it still hasn't become pragmatic for me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that as of NHibernate 5 the accepted answer "Unfortunately, NHibernate doesn't support that." is no longer correct:

> Starting with NHibernate 5.0, queries can also be created from an entity collection, with the standard Linq extension AsQueryable available from System.Linq namespace.
>
> ```
> IList<Cat> whiteKittens =
>     cat.Kittens.AsQueryable()
>         .Where(k => k.Color == "white")
>         .ToList();
> ```
>
> https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html

Can't speak definitively about the rest of the answer and comments in 2019 vs. 2014, regarding the practicability of Persistence Ignorance with NHibernate ORM, though I'm trying *really* hard to make it work as much as possible...we'll see.